# Python QThread variable not behing sent

Tags: python, signals, qthread

I'm using a thread from `qthread`.
Inside the thread I calculate an angle that I send to the main so that the GUI gets updated.

However the values that I get inside [to] rotate image are strange.
The angle calculated in the thread is for example `45.66619997018314` but what I get inside the function is `-433762864`.

I know basics of python and learning QT so please be patient

Thanks in advance

I'm using this thread:

```
import settings
import util

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import time
import screenrec
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class CompassThread(QThread):
    rotateImage = pyqtSignal(int)
    updateVariables = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._isRunning = True

    def run(self):
        while self._isRunning == True:
            settings.currentAngle = screenrec.getCurrentAngleCV()
            print("set", settings.currentAngle)
            self.rotateImage.emit(settings.currentAngle)
            time.sleep(2)

    def stop(self):
        self._isRunning = False
        self.terminate()
```

The function that I'm calling is this one:

```
def rotate_image(self, angle):
    print("angle", angle)
    self.image = settings.compass_image
    self.image = util.rotateImage(self.image, settings.compassPreviousAngle)
    self.image = QtGui.QImage(self.image.data, self.image.shape[1], self.image.shape[0],
                              QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
    self.image_frame.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
    self.show()
```

In main I stated the thread like this:

```
        self.compassThread = compassthread.CompassThread(self)
        self.compassThread.rotateImage.connect(lambda angle: compassthread.rotate_image(self, angle))
        self.compassThread.updateVariables.connect(lambda angle: updateVariables(angle))
        self.compassThread.start()
```